# Inverse of a Matrix of Partial Derivatives

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, finsler-geometry

This is from the book Lectures on Finsler Geometry by Zhongmin Shen.I am stucked here to find inverse of $a_{ij}$ that is $a^{ij}$ and how to prove that $||\beta||<1$ so please help I have tried it many times but couldn’t do it.[image]

Comment: The title is not great. The matrix is the Gram matrix of *inner products* of the basis vectors. It's probably best to remove calculus entirely from the question and just look at the actual linear algebra problem with basis vectors $v_i$ for an $m$-dimensional subspace of $\Bbb R^{m+1}$.

Comment: Add after rotation you may assume WLOG $B=<b_1, 0000>$.

Comment: @MathWonk Since we're working with a non-orthonormal basis here, I'm not sure that is a valid step.

Comment: I'm actually confused. A non-standard norm is defined in the first line on $\Bbb R^m$, but then the symbol $\|\cdot\|$ is used for vectors on $\Bbb R^{m+1}$. The formula then uses $\mu=1,\dots,m$ everywhere even though $\mu$ now runs to $m+1$.  This seems pretty sloppy.

Comment: And what is "the norm of $\beta$ with respect to $\alpha$"? I thought $\|\cdot\|$ had already been defined. This is annoying, as the author is a coauthor of an entire text on Finsler geometry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $v_1,\dots,v_m$ be linearly independent vectors in $\Bbb R^{m+1}$, and let $B=(B_\mu)$ be a vector in their span. Let $a_{ij} = v_i\cdot v_j$, and let $(a^{ij})$ be the inverse matrix of $(a_{ij})$.

Write $B = \sum c_jv_j$. Then $b_i = B\cdot v_i = \sum a_{ij}c_j$, so we can solve for $c_j = \sum a^{ji}b_i$. It follows that
$$\sum B_\mu^2 = B\cdot B = \sum a_{ij}c_ic_j = \sum a_{ij}a^{ik}a^{j\ell}b_kb_\ell=\sum\delta_i^\ell a^{ik}b_kb_\ell=\sum a^{\ell k}b_kb_\ell.$$
It would seem the author's inequality should be an equality.